# What is the JavaScript equivalent for Swift ?? operator

Tags: javascript, swift

In swift, `x = y ?? z` means that x equals y, unless y is null/nil, in which case, x equals z. What is the JavaScript equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) will achieve a similar result

```
x = (y ? y : z)
```

Strictly speaking to avoid [implicit typeconversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion) you may want something like

```
x = (null !== y ? y : z)
```

Short circuit assignment like `x = x || y` feels like a mis-use of the `||` operator which could lead to confusion down the road.  However I think it's a matter of taste which to use.

Comment: Do you mean to swap y and z to create `x = (null === y ? z : y)`?

Comment: Shorter code, both gurvinder372's and AnthonyAstige's answers were amazing and it was close

Answer (score 9):

```
x = y || z; //x is y unless y is null, undefined, "", '', or 0.
```

If you want to exclude `0` from `falsey` values then,

```
x = ( ( y === 0 || y ) ? y : z ); //x is y unless y is null, undefined, "", '', or 0.
```

Or if you want to exclude `false` as well from `falsey` values then,

```
x = ((y === 0 || y === false || y) ? y : z);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var testCases = [
  [0, 2],
  [false, 2],
  [null, 2],
  [undefined, 2],
  ["", 2],
  ['', 2],
]

for (var counter = 0; counter < testCases.length - 1; counter++) {
  var y = testCases[counter][0],
    z = testCases[counter][1],
    x = ((y === 0 || y === false || y) ? y : z);
  console.log("when y = " + y + " \t and z = " + z + " \t then x is " + x);
}
```

Comment: What if y is `false`